# AMD Kaveri + dedicated graphics card

Tags: cpu, gpu, hsa

I have read an article about an AMD technology used in *A series Kaveri* processors called [HSA](http://www.amd.com/en-gb/innovations/software-technologies/processors-for-business/compute-cores)

In few words they make processors with GPU cores, and HSA is basically a technology that makes the GPU help out the CPU cores, increasing the computing speed.

Their latest processor on the market (in A series) is the [A10-7870K](http://www.amd.com/en-gb/products/processors/desktop/a-series-apu#) that has 12 cores (4 CPU + 8 GPU).

My question is, if I have a dedicated graphics card, will the GPU cores still be used with HSA? Or the 8 GPU cores will be totally inactive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surprisingly, you can install a discrete GPU, AMD or non-AMD, and still have HSA-aware applications use the GCN cores on the APU for computations. [This](http://www.pcper.com/news/Processors/Fully-Enabling-A10-7850K-while-Utilizing-Standalone-GPU) article discusses that:

> Windows 7 and Windows 8 allow users to install multiple graphics
>   drivers from different vendors.  In my case I utilized a last
>   generation GTX 580 (the MSI N580GTX Lightning) along with the AMD A10
>   7850K.  These products coexist happily together on the MSI A88X-G45
>   Gaming motherboard.  The monitor is attached to the NVIDIA card and
>   all games are routed through that since it is the primary graphics
>   adapter.  Performance seems unaffected with both drivers active.

And the result:

> These results make me hopeful about the potential of AMD’s latest APU.
>   It can run side by side with a standalone card, and applications can
>   leverage the performance of this unit.  Now all we need is more HSA
>   aware software.  More time and more testing is needed for setups such
>   as this, and we need to see if HSA enabled software really does see a
>   boost from using the GPU portion of the APU as compared to a pure CPU
>   piece of software or code that will run on the standalone GPU.

Comment: I was google searching for information like this for at least 30 minutes without any luck, and You found it in a few minutes. I have red the article and if I understood it right, this technology is not developed enough but it works. I will need some more research to decide if I should upgrade my processor or wait for the technology to develop some more. Thank You.